# Recall a position in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm working with a data set that is coded as:

`{xdata,ydata,zdata}`

Since the data is collected in a serpentine pattern it spits out the data as:

`xdata={1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4}`
and
`ydata={1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4}`.

I'm trying to recall a specific zdata location using a LocatorPane on the ListDensityPlot with the following code:

```
pt={"some x value", "some y value"},
FirstPosition[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}], {n_ /; n >= pt[[1]] , n_ /; n >= pt[[2]]}]
```

However this returns Missing[NotFound]. Does anything have any tips or work arounds?

Comment: When you use the same pattern variable `n_` for both x and y, it will only match when they're equal; just rename the second one to `m_`.

Comment: Thank you so much!